# Multiple values are getting selected in radio options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Created the multiple radio options, but it is allowing me to select more then one option.

```
 {item.responseType === "radio" && (
                          <div className="form-control-wrap">
                            {item.options.split(",").map((list, index) => (
                              <Form.Check
                                key={index}
                                label={list}
                                name={list}
                                type="radio"
                                id={list}
                              />
                            ))}
                          </div>
                        )}
```

What changes need to be done to select only one option ?

Comment: Could you please check [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847127/react-select-only-one-radio-button-of-the-form-instead-of-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one of them to be selectable. You must set the value of the name props to the same value for all of them. like this

```
name="radio-name"  // use filed name
```

like this

```
{item.responseType === "radio" && (
  <div className="form-control-wrap">
    {item.options.split(",").map((list, index) => (
      <Form.Check
         key={index}
         label={list}
         name="radio-name"
         type="radio"
         id={list}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
)}
```